# Opencart language picker wierdly not working on few pages

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I have this wierd problem, on opencart 2.xx i have 2 languages and the language switcher is working fine on some and doing nothing on others, added to this language is randomly switching as i go through page.

I have no idea whan can cause this so i cant provide specific section of code.

I discovered that it works fine on pages that have some kind of imput, like login, register, cart, checkout etc.. And not working at all on others, dunno if its related tho.

Also theres this problem, also in header so maybe its corelated, when i add item to cart, go to different page, cart shows 0 until i hover it, after i hover it immediately shows correct number.

Example of page with NOT working switcher: http://corddecker.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=25_29

Example of page with working switcher: http://corddecker.com/index.php?route=account/login

If you can just check that behaviour and give me some idea what can be causing this, would be awesome because i have no idea.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've notice your theme is calling `magnificPopup` `function` in this address:

```
http://corddecker.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=25_29
```

And `jquery.magnific-popup.min.js` is not included in your theme.
This caused and error that can affect some of your other codes.
As by default Opencart 2.x comes with a copy of `jquery.magnific-popup.min.js` try to add this to your `header.tpl`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/magnific/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
```

and make sure the file exists on that directory.

Comment: Didnt help but thanks for advice, do you maybe have any other idea ?

Comment: `magnificPopup` needs `jQuery` to work, you have added it before `jquery`. that error still exists. try to reorder your `<script>`s and move `jquery.magnific-popup.min.js` bellow `jquery-2.1.1.min.js`.

Comment: error is fixed now, but it didnt fix language switcher problem, still the same behaviour, im clueless